# How to edit lines in ubuntu 12.04 LTS Update Manager

Tags: 12.04

Every time I try to update my system the update manager tells me that there is a problem on line two concerning a docking program I downloaded and installed. I just want to delete or skip this line so the update manager can move on, other wise it just stops at this line. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What file does it say the two lines are in?

Answer (score 1):

You will want to edit your `/etc/apt/sources.list` and comment out the 2nd line. The easiest way to edit it is to use the Ubuntu Software Center and under the "Edit ->> Software Sources" you can uncheck the offending PPA in the "Other Software" tab.